# Can't view uploaded image in Firebase Storage in Flutter desktop

Tags: typescript, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I keep getting `Exception: Invalid image data` after getting the download url from my cloud function. Even after I manually download the image onto my system, when I open the image I get an error saying that it has an invalid file format or it's corrupted. When I open it in chrome, I just see a placeholder image. The file occupies space/has size but it can't be read.

I've tried a lot of things like:

- Constructing a public url
- Getting a signed url
- Making the file public and setting the public parameter to true
- Giving my service account increased permissions to read storage metadata/info
- Uploading/Downloading a binary
- Uploading/Downloading a base64 encoded bytes
- Setting storages rules to `allow read, write: if true`

  And many others I can't remember.

I've checked out many other functions on this site , articles and github and tried them but the same issue.

This is one of the current iterations of my cloud function

```
import { logger } from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp, ServiceAccount } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { Storage } from "@google-cloud/storage";
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import { credential } from "firebase-admin";
import { default as serviceAccountData } from "@key/service-account-key.json";

const projectID = "vra-client-service-app";

const serviceAccount = serviceAccountData as ServiceAccount;

initializeApp({
  credential: credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectID,
  keyFilename: "service-account-key.json",
});

// Define the shape of the request object
interface UploadFileRequest {
  file: string; // raw binary data

  // Path where the file will be saved in Firebase Cloud Storage
  storagePath: string;

  // MIME type of the image
  mimeType: string;
}

// Define the shape of the success response
interface SuccessResponse {
  message: string;
  downloadUrl: string;
}

// Define the shape of the error response
interface ErrorResponse {
  error: string;
}

export const uploadFile = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  console.log("Function uploadFile started");

  if (request.method !== "POST") {
    const errorResponse: ErrorResponse = { error: "Method not allowed" };

    response.status(405).json(errorResponse);

    return;
  }

  const data: UploadFileRequest = request.body;

  try {
    const bucketName = `${projectID}.appspot.com`;
    const storagePath = data.storagePath;
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
    const file = bucket.file(storagePath);

    const decodedData = Buffer.from(data.file, "base64");

    await file.save(decodedData, {
      contentType: data.mimeType,
      public: true, // If you don't want the file to be publicly accessible
    });

    const downloadUrl = await file.getSignedUrl({
      action: "read",
      expires: "03-09-2491",
    });

    const successResponse: SuccessResponse = {
      message: "File uploaded successfully",
      downloadUrl: downloadUrl[0],
    };

    response.status(200).json(successResponse);
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    // Handle errors by logging them and returning an error message
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      logger.error(error);

      const errorResponse: ErrorResponse = { error: error.message };

      response.status(500).json(errorResponse);
    } else {
      logger.error("Unknown error:", error);

      const errorResponse: ErrorResponse = {
        error: "An unknown error occurred",
      };

      response.status(500).json(errorResponse);
    }
  }
});
```

And one of the current iterations of my upload and download.

```
Future<Result<UploadFileSuccessResponse, String>> uploadProfilePicture({
    required String fileName,
    required String filePath,
    required String email,
  }) async {
    return Chain.capture(() async {
      final mimeType = lookupMimeType(filePath);

      if (mimeType == null) {
        logger.e("Failed to get mime type for $filePath");

        return const Result.error("Failed to get mime type");
      }

      final file = File(filePath);

      final uploadFileRequest = UploadFileRequest(
        encodedFileBytes: base64Encode(await file.readAsBytes()),
        storagePath: "admins/$email/profilePicture/$fileName",
        mimeType: mimeType,
      );

      try {
        logger.i("Uploading ${uploadFileRequest.mimeType}.. $fileName");

        final response = await _dio.post<Map<String, dynamic>>(
          "/uploadFile",
          data: uploadFileRequest.toJson(),
        );

        final data = response.data;

        if (data == null) {
          return const Result.error("Failed to upload profile picture");
        }

        var uploadFileSuccessResponse =
            UploadFileSuccessResponse.fromJson(data);

        logger.i(
          "Message ${uploadFileSuccessResponse.message} Download URL: "
          "${uploadFileSuccessResponse.downloadUrl}",
        );

        final firebaseResponse = await _dio.get<List<int>>(
          uploadFileSuccessResponse.downloadUrl,
          options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
        );

        final imageData = firebaseResponse.data;

        if (imageData != null) {
          uploadFileSuccessResponse = uploadFileSuccessResponse.copyWith(
            imageBytes: imageData,
          );

          // final appDirectory = await getTemporaryDirectory();

          // final newImagePath = "${appDirectory.path}/$fileName";

          // final newImageFile = File(newImagePath);

          // if (newImageFile.existsSync()) {
          //   // Delete the old file if it exists
          //   await newImageFile.delete();
          // }

          // final file = await newImageFile.writeAsBytes(uint8List);

          // logger.i("Saving image ${file.runtimeType} to $newImagePath");
        }

        // final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

        // final image = await _dio.download(
        //   uploadFileSuccessResponse.downloadUrl,
        //   "${tempDir.path}/$fileName",
        //   options: Options(
        //     responseType: ResponseType.stream,
        //   ),
        // );

        // final imageData = image.data.readAsBytes();

        // final imageData = await newImageFile.readAsBytes();

        // logger.i("imageData type: ${imageData}");

        // final imageMem = Image.memory(imageData);

        // logger.i("imageMem type: ${imageMem.runtimeType}");

        // final mimeType = lookupMimeType(newImageFile.path);

        return Result.success(uploadFileSuccessResponse);
      } on DioException catch (e, stackTrace) {
        final data = e.response?.data;

        if (data != null) {
          final uploadFileErrorResponse =
              UploadFileErrorResponse.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>);

          logger.e(
            "Failed to upload profile picture: "
            "${uploadFileErrorResponse.error}",
          );

          return Result.error(uploadFileErrorResponse.error);
        }

        final terseStacktrace = Chain.forTrace(stackTrace).terse;

        logger
          ..e("Failed to upload profile picture", [e, terseStacktrace])
          ..e("Error ${e.error} Message ${e.message} Response ${e.response}");

        return const Result.error("Failed to upload profile picture");
      } catch (e, stackTrace) {
        final terseStacktrace = Chain.forTrace(stackTrace).terse;

        logger.wtf("Failed to upload profile picture", [e, terseStacktrace]);

        rethrow;
      }
    });
  }
```

I don't think the issue is on the client side because I see `Error loading preview` when I open the bucket on the firebase console. Opening the link runs into the same issue. What do I do now?

Note: I'm using Flutter on desktop so I can't use the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix, the data models weren't equal. Specifically

`file: string; // raw binary data` was named differently on the client side, I fixed it by being consistent. I also removed the service account completely because it wasn't necessary and added the Service Account Token Creator permission to the compute service account so that the signed urls can be generated by the function.